# How can i get MAC address of client machine in jsp

Tags: jsp, jsf

I am developing one application for secure voting system. I need to get MAC address of a particular machine to set as 'voting machine'. How can I get MAC address of a client machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            //InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.46.53");

            /*
             * Get NetworkInterface for the current host and then read the
             * hardware address.
             */
            NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
            if (ni != null) {
                byte[] mac = ni.getHardwareAddress();
                if (mac != null) {
                    /*
                     * Extract each array of mac address and convert it to hexa with the
                     * following format 08-00-27-DC-4A-9E.
                     */
                    for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                        System.out.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "");
                    }
                } else {
                    // Address doesn't exist or is not accessible.
                }
            } else {
                // Network Interface for the specified address is not found.
            }
```

Comment: How can i get client's MAC address using JSP?

Comment: See these video tutorials, it may help you :) http://www.vtc.com/products/Java-2-JSP-and-Servlets-tutorials.htm

Comment: did it throw an error or exception ? or it returned false results ? take care that we entered a virtual IP and you have to replace it

Comment: You are welcome, please don't forget to push it up and mark it as answer :)

Comment: I am getting null for macAddress

Comment: @AshrafBashir are You sure, is this OK in servlet container / whole stack? I'm not sure

Answer (score -1):

The following is the code i implemented and it worked for me. This code is from : [Get mac address ip address in jsp java](http://amitkgaur.blogspot.com/2010/08/get-mac-address-ip-address-in-jsp-java.html).

The Code is as follows:

```
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>


<%
InetAddress inetAddress;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String ipAddress="",macAddress="";
int i=0;
try {
    inetAddress=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    ipAddress=inetAddress.getHostAddress();
    NetworkInterface network=NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(inetAddress);
     byte[] hw=network.getHardwareAddress();
     for(i=0; i<hw.length; i++)
        sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", hw[i], (i < hw.length - 1) ? "-" : 
         ""));    
    macAddress=sb.toString();
  } catch(Exception e) {
   out.print("<br/>"+e.toString());
    macAddress="-";
  }
  out.print("<br/>"+ipAddress);
  out.print("<br/>"+macAddress);
 %>
```